# Change Ionic 4 progress bar color using ngStyle

Tags: angular, ionic4

```
<ion-progress-bar [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.color}" 
value="{{item.modifiedProgress}}" >
</ion-progress-bar>
```

I added this progress bar inside `*ngfor` loop. I want to add `item.color` value as progress bar color. I used RGB color format.

Comment: <ion-progress-bar [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.color}" value="{{item.modifiedProgress}}" ></ion-progress-bar>

Comment: I used the RGB color format as 'item.color' value

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in stackblitz or plunker?

Comment: Have you tried using the custom CSS property for ion-progress-bar?  `[ngStyle]="{'--background': item.color}"` https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/progress-bar#css-custom-properties

Comment: Yes I tried<ion-progress-bar [ngStyle]="{'--background': item.color}" class="bar1" value="0.25" ></ion-progress-bar>

Comment: You have not defined what your problem is?

Comment: This is stackblitz  link:https://angular-ztywq5.stackblitz.io but in stackblitz I couldn't run the code but hope you will get an idea what I was going to do.

Comment: @Tomas Vancoillie [ngStyle]="{'--background':item.color}" is it working for you?

Comment: these things didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Please do not wrestle , just use the style tag.

```
style="--progress-background: {{item.color}};"
```

working fine.